# Cannot Install anything from the Software Center in 12.10

Tags: installation, software-center, package-management, 12.10, plugins

I just downloaded 12.10 and I can't seem to download and install anything, from plugins to programs, from the Software Center.

It says

> Not Found. There isn’t a software package called “name” in your current software sources.

I've tried a couple of proposed solution from here but nothing is working.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Try these command.

They worked for me, See if it works for you :

This command clears the current list of software sources :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

This command downloads and refreshes the list :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I've been trying to figure this out for the last five hours until I stumbled upon your answer. No matter what I did, apt-get did not work. You are awesome